# Here Maps - Autocomplete Suggestion

Tags: here-api

I am looking at using the Autocomplete API from Here Maps and using the Suggestion.json endpoint. My question is that as a user keys in characters, the autocomplete API for suggestions will be called on every key press. This means that for each key press, I need to call the API. This will turn out to be quite expensive. Assuming, I type in "London", it will call the API 6 times. Is there a better way to do this? Also, is there any option of a session token to be created such that, I get charged only for a session token in which I key in multiple characters for a search suggestion list to be generated?

Comment: What technology are you using in the frontend? You want to do a search for "debounce" any way, for example: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you can do to reduce the number of calls:

1. Some places have just short names like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_short_place_names, so you might have to consider even single character names for your autosuggest. So you may consider building a cache of autosuggest keywords i.e. say a user types L and the one time you make a call to autosuggest API, you can cache the result with L as Key and then for the next key press repeat building the data structure or data store per your requirement, so that the number of hits to the API gradually decreases.
   Once you have built your cache, you can decide to refresh you cache after every 10 calls or so. This will greatly reduce your call to the external API.
   Lookup Trie data structure. might be helpful.
2. Here bills you based on the number of requests you make to the backend services so there is not such possibility to bill by session token. You can talk to your account executive if you can negotiate the cost of the offering though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily with the Javascript API: here's an [example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.19.2/dev_guide/topics/geocoding.html) to get started and [here's](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.19.2/api_reference/H.service.SearchService.html#autosuggest) the documentation page for autosuggest Javascript API.

Comment: Updating the links: [example here] (https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.30.12/dev_guide/topics/geocoding.html#autosuggest) and [autosuggest doc here] (https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.30.12/api_reference/H.service.SearchService.html#autosuggest)